# Cannot find index of array in fragment except index of 0

Tags: java, android

I have problem passing data from Activity(Main) to Fragment(First).

In my Main I declare a variable to be STATIC as I want to use in First. I noticed that when I want to display array of the variable it only shown index of 0. While , when index other than 0 it will shown an exception.

```
 public static String tps = ""; //declare it on top in Main.




 final String[] populateTPS = new String[1]; //it will save in 1 element of array`



 populateTPS[0] = part3[2]; //populateTPS[0] because when i want to make populate [] it will give an error.



  tps=populateTPS[0]; //this is in Main and In First, I will use the static variable tps
```

But when I want to display specific index of this string array it not gonna work.

Is this because fragment problem? Because when I try it in Activity,it WORKS.

//IN Activity

```
  ` final String[] populateRPM = new String[2]; // length is 2.
```

`populateRPM[0] =(part3[3]);`

```
String []populateRpmData= populateRPM[0].split(" ");


 pr.setText( populateRpmData[3]);//it works
```

Comment: In simple words, if you want to pass data to fragment then make static method of instance in of that fragment and pass parameter in it.

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work, as well as the error message/exception.

Comment: `final String[] populateTPS = new String[1];` will create array of length 1 and will assign it to `populateTPS ` variable. Since that variable is `final` it will always hold that array (with length 1, so with only one valid index `[0]`). Having array with only one element is kind of pointless since you could store that one element directly in variable instead of array. So what are you trying to do here?

Comment: remove the word final

Comment: @Guy this is the error but i already set it.   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @SarthakGandhi cannot.because when i remove it.it said that tps is accessed in inner class should be final.

Comment: @Piyush i also try to use bundle but i dont want to talk in here because it is not related about this problem

Comment: declare tps on top of the class

Comment: `data` is `null`. somewhere along the way you set `MainActivity.tps` to `null`, probably in the first code block.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi already declare it

Comment: @Pshemo i know it will create array of length 1 and will assign it.But when i change to populateTPS[ ]  or put any index except zero it will crash.

Comment: @Pshemo  I also change final String[] populateTPS = new String[10]; to become length of 10. It also not gonna work.

Comment: I am confused. If you "know it will create array of length 1" then you shouldn't be surprised by fact that it will crash for "any index except zero". Anyway IMO this question is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). With [mcve] we could explain why some error happens, but still without clearly described purpose of this code (what do you *want* it to do) we still wouldn't be able to suggest any solution. So could you [edit] your question and clarify what you are after first?

Comment: @Pshemo ok let say i alredy changed the length to become 10.But why it cannot display any index except zero? I just want to display of that String in array.But why when i want to display only String it work?

Comment: "why it cannot display any index except zero" cause of the problem is usually explained by error you are getting. If it is IndexOutOfBoundException then you used index which was lesser < 0 or >= array.length. If it is NullPointerException it may be related by fact that String arrays are filled with `null`s. So `new String[3]` would create array like `{null, null, null}` NOT `{"", "", ""}` so if you don't first assign proper value at index you want to read you may end up reading `null` value and calling any accessor like `array[2].isEmpty()` would be same as `null.isEmpty()` which throws NPE.

Comment: @Pshemo I understand what you said.But I already changed the length but it not works too.It only work if index is 0.